# Adding a column of differences from another column to groups of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following example code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar','foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                   'B' : np.random.randint(0,100,8)})
```

What I want to do now is to add a new column C to the dataframe which contains the values which result from grouping the df by column A, sorting the groups by B, and calculating the differences of the values of B and the following value.

Is this even possible with a few lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html):

```
df['C'] = df.sort_values(['A','B']).groupby('A')['B'].diff()
print (df)
     A   B     C
0  foo  44  23.0
1  bar  47  38.0
2  foo  64  20.0
3  bar  67  20.0
4  foo  67   3.0
5  bar   9   NaN
6  foo  83  16.0
7  foo  21   NaN
```

Detail:

```
print (df.sort_values(['A','B']))
     A   B
5  bar   9
1  bar  47
3  bar  67
7  foo  21
0  foo  44
2  foo  64
4  foo  67
6  foo  83

print (df.sort_values(['A','B']).groupby('A')['B'].diff())
5     NaN
1    38.0
3    20.0
7     NaN
0    23.0
2    20.0
4     3.0
6    16.0
Name: B, dtype: float64
```

Alternative solution:

```
df['C'] = (df.groupby('A')['B'] 
             .apply(lambda x: x.sort_values().diff())
             .reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
```